# How to use JQuery AJAX with Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ide, cloud9-ide

I'm using Cloud9 IDE. My goal is to be able to develop applications that use JQuery AJAX.

I have these 2 files:

1. test.htm

`<p class="result">the result</p>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$.get('test.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
</script>
```

`2. test.php

`<?php
 echo "hello world";
    ?>`

The problem is that the paragarph with class "result" should read "hello world". Instead, the entire contents of the php file are being added.

How do I get the php file to just echo "hello world" as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not able to run PHP scripts in Cloud9IDE. This possibility will be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your .php script from a web server with PHP installed for it to be executed, and it needs to be wrapped in `<?php /*code*/ ?>`

Comment: My real code is wrapped in php open/close tags. It took a few edits for me to get those to show here. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your php code needs to be wrapped with these tags:

```
<?php echo "Hello world";?>
```

Comment: My real code is wrapped in php open/close tags. It took a few edits for me to get those to show here. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you see "Hello world" when you access test.php in your browser?

Comment: I'm not able to view test.php in the browser. I'm previewing it using Cloud9 IDE. When I try to view test.php, I get forwarded back to test.htm.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. If you can't view it in your browser, then that's a server issue, not a jQuery issue. Set up your IDE server to render the PHP page, then try again.

Comment: Thanks Picardo. Yes, that is the core of the issue: How do I setup my Cloud9 IDE server to render the PHP page?

Comment: I haven't used that IDE before, but someone else here can help you.I'd suggest asking the question again using Cloud9 tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the php code in php open/close tags

```
<?php
 echo "hello world";
?>
```

Comment: My real code is wrapped in php open/close tags. It took a few edits for me to get those to show here. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you see the <?php & ?> tags in the response? if that's the case the server isn't configured to run php. It just returns it as plain text

Comment: Yes, that is the core of the issue: How do I setup my Cloud9 IDE server to render the PHP page?

Comment: According to this post http://cloud9ide.posterous.com/ they *plan* to have php support soon. So my guess is it's not currently possible